# Analysing data in a text file

Tags: python

I have a txt file with data like this:

```
Kimberly,43,68,176,8
William,42,47,162,15
Dorothy,55,103,160,6
Michael,37,126,133,8,54
...
```

*(4 questions: age, height, weight, exercise time - answers are the numbers, some have more than 4 and are meant to be handled via an error log and ignored and removed from the calculation, error log reports data with too many or too few pieces of data)*

I have two things I need to do. One is to print the average (mean) values of each question in, this format:

```
Question    Average
-------------------------------
1           Value     etc.
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get data from just one "column" of the text file. I need to ignore the name, which is in the first column, and then just use e.g. the second column.

Could someone please guide me as to how to do that? And also with the error processing; I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: check csv standard lib module https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: as @DynoHongjunFu said, use the `csv` library. Setting up a `csv.reader` can parse a file, like the one above, into lists (where each row is a list). These can then be indexed as normal in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will get you started.  I didn't approach your formatting or error checking requirements, but this script provides the mean of the first row.

The answer to how you get values from just one row is to create a list of rows, then access the column you want using its index: aRow[theIndexOfTheColumnYouWant].  In this example, line[1] gets you the values from the age column.

```
import csv

with open('text.txt', 'rb') as myFile:
    # create a csv.reader() object
    reader = csv.reader(myFile)
    # instantiate a list to store the values of the first row in
    secondColumnNums = []
    # loop over the reader object, appending each column two ([1]) value to firstLine
    for line in reader:
        secondColumnNums.append(float(line[1]))
    # add secondColumnNums together and divide by how many numbers there are (the mean)
    theMean = sum(secondColumnNums)/len(secondColumnNums)
    print "The mean of the ages (column two) is {}.".format(theMean)
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply! how can I do this without importing the csv library though?

Comment: you're welcome. :)  have you been forbidden from importing a module to help you with this?  if so, try .split()-ing each line by commas to generate a list similar to the above, then iterate over that.  the most efficient way is to use the csv module, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is `csv` module in the Python standard library.

```
>>> import csv
>>> x='''Kimberly,43,68,176,8
... William,42,47,162,15
... Dorothy,55,103,160,6
... Michael,37,126,133,8,54'''
>>> with open("/tmp/a.csv", "w") as fp:
...  fp.write(x)
... 
>>> with open("/tmp/a.csv") as fp:
...   reader = csv.reader(fp)
...   for row in reader:
...     print(row[1])
... 
43
42
55
37
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply! how can I do this without importing the csv library though?